# Angular parameterized route change parameter but maintain the rest of the route

Tags: angular, routes

I'll preface this by saying I can, of course, take the current url and strip out what I want and replace it but that feels wrong within the context of the angular router.

If we consider the following route path:

```
/item/:id/details
```

If I would like to just change the id and maintain the rest of the route - `/item/123/details` to `/item/abc/details` what is the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: what you mean by changing id? content of application will remain same or changed based on id?

Comment: The content of the application will change based on the id. The user is able to select different items from a component on the page and it will change the detail view. I do not want the routing to go back to just `/item/:id/details`. I'm not sure on the best approach and I was curious if there was any other options than `.replace` on the url.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of interest in this question I opted to just go for my initial implementation of

```js
const url = location.href.replace(location.origin, '').replace(oldId, newId);
this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
```